# Hangman Tkinter GUI - Trouble with for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm coding a GUI with Tkinter for a python [hangman game](http://pastebin.com/wAMUsxka). I'm running into some trouble with my `for` loop that I use to replace the blanks of the hidden word with the actual letter that corresponds with the blank when the letter is guessed by the user. This is the loop:

```
def reveal(self, start=False, full=False):
    global hiddenWord, charList

    if start == True:
        for i in answerWord:
            if i == " ":
                charList.append(" ")
            else:
                charList.append("__")
        hiddenWord.set(" ".join(charList))

    elif full == True:
        hiddenWord.set(answerWord)

    else:
        c = guess.get()            
        for i in answerWord:
            if i == c.lower():
                charList[answerWord.index(i)] = i
            elif i == c.upper():
                charList[answerWord.index(i)] = i
        hiddenWord.set(" ".join(charList))
```

The problem that I am having is that, when I run the program and the hidden word is one with multiple occurrences of the same letter, occasionally, only the first occurrence of the letter will be replaced. Here is one instance where this issue occurred when the word was 'california':
[california missing second 'i' and second 'a'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkf3l.gif). Now, this does not happen all of the time and I haven't been able to debug the problem because I can't seem to find any common factors between the instances where it does occur. I am a novice when it comes to Tkinter, so I acknowledge that my program is a little sloppy as I am still trying to get into the swing of things. Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Can you send my your full code in a pastebin? (www.pastebin.com) I need to see some of the logic you are using.

Comment: It's hyperlinked to 'hangman game' in my post. http://pastebin.com/wAMUsxka

Comment: Are the text files anywhere?

Comment: Try changing your for loop to `for i in range(0,answerWord.count(c))` instead of `for i in answerWord`.

Comment: Here is a link to all files referenced in the full project code: https://psu.box.com/s/4betfddrmdekd7xmzl957rl34s5vh8fv

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused That would fundamentally change the logic of the for loop.

Comment: That is what is required. I've made my own one of these, you need to run the replace loop as many times as there are letters in the answer. To do this, using lists in the best option. Unfortunately, I can't really make sense of any of the code without comments, so I'm struggling to help.

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused Right now, the `for` loop is iterating through every letter in the word, and checking to see if that letter is equal to the guessed letter. If I used your approach, the for loop would no longer be iterating through the letters in the word, it would be iterating through integers 0 through the number of occurrences of the guessed letter.

Comment: Okay, so if you know how many times the letter appears, you can then check where this letter appears, and replace it. So, if you have a list `['_','_','_']` for the word `"ana"`, you see A appears twice, for the first iteration you take the first A, replace it to get `['a','_','_']`, and then remove this first 'a', giving you `"_na"`. On the second iteration, you see another a in the last position, so you take it, replace it, getting `['a','_','a']` and then `"_n_"`. Then you take the next guess. In this example you have two lists, the list that starts blank, and the list with the word in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, I was able to solve my problem by editing the logic of the `for` loop as such:

```
else:
        c = guess.get()            
        for i in range(0,len(answerWord)):
            if answerWord[i] == c.lower():
                charList[i] = answerWord[i]
            elif answerWord[i] == c.upper():
                charList[i] = answerWord[i]
        hiddenWord.set(" ".join(charList))
```